# Parsing input into tokens using different delimiters in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, delimiter, c-strings

So I am trying to parse input data and break up the data into string tokens, the problem is, I sometimes need different delimiters on the same line and on different lines, all at the same time. Here is an example of what I need to parse:

Input:

> ```
> <15>
> algorithm [binary tree] analysis heap
> <1>
> [binary search tree] analysis
> complexity algorithm [2-3 tree]
> <5>
> tree [b+ tree] [Binary Tree]
> <8>
> graph clique Tree
> <5>
> tree [full binary tree]
> [complete binary tree]
> <-1>
> ```

So from the above input, I need to take parse the numbers inside angle brackets using a delimeter <> which I have done and works in my code. Then I need to parse all the data on those lines using both the dilemeter " " for individual words, and "[]" as a delimeter for the words inside the brackets which need to have the spaces included.

So this is currently what I have:

```
// create a file-reading object
ifstream fin;
fin.open("input.txt"); // open a file
if (!fin.good())
return 1; // exit if file not found

// read each line of the file
while (!fin.eof())
{
// read an entire line into memory
char buf[maxChars];
fin.getline(buf, maxChars);
cout << "The line I'm about to read is: "<<  buf << endl;

int n = 0; // a for-loop index

// array to store memory addresses of the tokens in buf
char* token[maxTokens] = {}; // initialize to 0

// parse the line into <> delimited tokens first
token[0] = strtok(buf, "<>"); // number tokens with <> delimeters
if (token[0])
{
  token[1] = strtok(token[0], "[]"); //break tokens by spaces
  for (n = 1; n <20; n++)
  {
    token[n]=strtok(NULL, " "); //break tokens by brackets
    if (!token[n]) break; // no more tokens
  }
}

// process (print) the tokens
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // n = #of tokens
  cout << "Token[" << i << "] = " << token[i] << endl;
cout << endl;
}
```

and I get this kind of output:

> ```
> The line I'm about to read is: <15>
> Token[0] = 15
> ```

```
The line I'm about to read is: algorithm [binary tree] analysis heap
Token[0] = algorithm 
Token[1] = binary tree
Token[2] =  analysis heap

The line I'm about to read is: <1>
Token[0] = 1

The line I'm about to read is: [binary search tree] analysis
Token[0] = [binary search tree
Token[1] =  analysis

The line I'm about to read is: complexity algorithm [2-3 tree]
Token[0] = complexity algorithm 
Token[1] = 2-3 tree

The line I'm about to read is: <5>
Token[0] = 5

The line I'm about to read is: tree [b+ tree] [Binary Tree]
Token[0] = tree 
Token[1] = b+ tree
Token[2] =  
Token[3] = Binary Tree

The line I'm about to read is: <8>
Token[0] = 8

The line I'm about to read is: graph clique Tree
Token[0] = graph clique Tree

The line I'm about to read is: <5>
Token[0] = 5

The line I'm about to read is: tree [full binary tree]
Token[0] = tree 
Token[1] = full binary tree

The line I'm about to read is: [complete binary tree]
Token[0] = [complete binary tree

The line I'm about to read is: <-1>
Token[0] = -1
```

Basically I need it to look like:

> Token[0] = 15
>       Token[0] = algorithm
>       Token[1] = binary tree
>       Token[2] = analysis
>       Token[3] = heap
>   and etc....

Comment: What have you tried so far to find the problem in the code? You seem to just use the wrong input data. You're reading a single line and then you expect to have the whole file.

Comment: It is reading a line at a time through a while loop so I am getting the whole file (as you can see in my output). The problem is not that I think I have an error, its more that I don't understand how to do what I need.

Comment: I misread your output because of the broken code block, so I thought the first part is what you get and the second is what you want to get. I think you're doing well. You just need to concentrate on the issues and carefully tune it from the beginning to the end. Currently there's nothing to be answered, I would even consider just deleting the question and starting a new one when you have some specific issue to ask about.